# How to disable CALC command in excel import

Tags: java, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have an CSV import which gets data for various column.

One of the column stores values as firstName,LastName.
It fails when i have firstName/lastName as

```
'=2-2+CMD|' /C CALC'!A0'
```

It opens calculator while opening CSV.

While i edit the CSV and append "=" ahead of it for eg

```
="=2-2+CMD|' /C CALC'!A0 , lastName"
```

it displays it correct. But while adding same in code it moves my 'lastName' to next column. I need to disable this calc command somehow while keeping the command within the file.

Comment: Are you specifying Text as the column data type during import?

Comment: No, as it is currently working for all other cases

Comment: Excel thinks the `=` sign means that the cell contains a formula.